# Solr Search within the child and return all the siblings

Tags: solr

I basically need to search within child document and get only the siblings of the matched child document.
  I have a below query which returns parent document and ALL child document including the matched child document.

```
q = {!parent which=content_type:parentDocument}bibid:8024  // bibid is a child node
fl = *,[child parentFilter=content_type:parentDocument childFilter=content_type:childLoansDocument]
```

I am using Solr 8.3.0.
  Please help

Comment: Do you have an example? Since what you describe - all child documents - means the same thing as "return the siblings of the matched child document". The siblings of the matched child document are all the child documents of the same parent document.

Comment: So, based on your actual reqest you just need to exclude from the results the child document itself, you will get all its siblings.

Comment: I need to have only the sibling child documents of the matched one. Currently, I have no way to exclude the parent document from the result set.